# How to Customize Jenkins Views

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I would like to add multiple *boolean parameters* in a `jenkins` job as a **checklist**. I don't want to add each one in a new separate **div**. I was wondering if I could manipulate the `HTML/CSS` of `jenkins` in order to group these multiple *boolean parameters*, maybe give each group a header as well.

Here is an image of what I have in mind.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See Jenkins' [Simple Theme Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin):

> *A plugin for Jenkins that supports custom CSS & JavaScript.*
>
> *At Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Theme, you could configure urls of CSS and JavaScript.*

Answer (score -1):

- Install Simple Theme Plugin
- Go to the JENKINS_HOME/userContent directory
- Create the layout directory
- Create the style.css file.

Example of Simple Theme Plugin configuration:
URL of theme css http://localhost:8080/jenkins/usercontent/layout/style.css